# Capture Unicode command line output

Tags: delphi, unicode, command-prompt, widechar, console-output

I have a procedure to capture a hidden Command Prompt window and display the output in a `TMemo`. This is the same/similar code that is posted all over the internet and Stack Overflow:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  commandline,workdir:string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure GetDosOutput;
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255000] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  Handle: Boolean;
  thisline,tmpline,lastline:string;
  commandstartms:int64;
  p1,p2:integer;
begin
  with SA do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(SA);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
      cb := SizeOf(SI);
      dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
      hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
      hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    end;
    lastline:='';

    Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PWideChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine),
                            nil, nil, True, 0, nil,
                            PWideChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);

    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255000, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead>0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead]:=#0;
            Form1.CommandMemo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
            thisline:=string(buffer);

            Form1.CommandMemo.text:=Form1.CommandMemo.text+thisline;

            //auto-scroll to end of memo
            SendMessage(Form1.CommandMemo.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0,Form1.CommandMemo.Lines.Count-1);
            Form1.CommandMemo.Lines.EndUpdate;
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     commandline:='tree c:';
     workdir:='c:\';
     GetDosOutput;
end;
```

That works as expected for any ASCII output but does not support Unicode characters.

When the `tree` command runs it normally displays characters like:

```
│   │   │   │   │   ├───
```

...but the Memo displays:

```
³   ³           ³   ÃÄÄÄ
```

I tried changing the buffer from `AnsiChar` to `Char` and that does get Unicode displaying in the Memo, but those are just corrupted Unicode characters and not what the command line is showing:

```
††††‱楦敬猨 潭敶⹤਍††††‱楦敬猨 潭敶⹤਍䕈䑁椠⁳潮⁷瑡〠捣攰ㅥ⁢敍杲⁥異汬爠煥敵瑳⌠㤷㔴映潲⁭⵷ⵥ⽷楦⵸浩条ⵥ潤湷捳污੥汁敲摡⁹灵琠⁯慤整ਮㅥ⁢敍杲⁥異汬爠煥敵††††‱楦敬猨 潭敶⹤਍††††‱楦敬猨 潭敶⹤਍⁭⵷ⵥ⽷楦⵸浩条ⵥ潤湷捳污੥
```

Can anyone help tweak that code to support times when the command line uses Unicode characters?  I have been messing around with this for hours now trying the suggestions below, but none of them get the tree output displaying correctly in the memo.  Can anyone can fix my example code here or post code that works with D11?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a sample input (what you expect) and corrupted output (what you get).

Comment: When you use [pipes, you need to use `/U`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), too.

Comment: That sounded like a solution, but adding /U to the createprocess cmd.exe commandline did not make any difference.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): the 1st example  `'│ ├───'.encode( 'cp850').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `³ ÃÄÄÄ` and the 2nd (truncated) `'‱楦敬猨 潭敶⹤਍††††‱楦敬猨'.encode( 'utf-16-le'). decode( 'utf-8')` returns `1 file(s) moved.\r\n        1 file(s`

Comment: Since you program doesn't crash you effectively call [`CreateProcessA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and not [`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) - the latter needs a writeable second parameter instead of a literal only. Run Unicode, get Unicode.

Comment: @AmigoJack [-A vs. -W APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page#-a-vs--w-apis) in  [Use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) here… The 2nd mojibake described above shows rather `CreateProcessW` in effect…

Comment: OK, changing to CreateProcessW doesn't seem to help.  Using AnsiChar, Char and WideChar no help.  /U added to cmd.exe no help.
Can you try the reproducible code to see if you can get it working?

Comment: Nobody reads my links either: "_`lpCommandLine`: The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation._" - hence `CreateProcessA()` is used here, because `W()` would crash on a literal.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me using Delphi 7 in Windows 7, giving the following output:

```
...
El día de la bestia (1995)
Jo Nesbø's Headhunters - Hodejegerne (2011)
Léon (Directors Cut) (1994)
Sånger från andra våningen - Songs from the Second Floor (2000)
دختری در شب تنها به خانه می‌رود - A Girl Walks Home Alone at Night (2014)
アウトレイジ ビヨンド - Outrage - Beyond (2012)
アキレスと亀 - Achilles and the Tortoise (2008)
葉問3 - Ip Man 3 (2015)
賽德克•巴萊 - Warriors of the Rainbow - Seediq Bale (2011)
살인의 추억 - Memories of Murder (2003)
신세계 - New World (2013)
...
```

[image: Screenshot of Unicode console output]

My major differences are:

- Delphi 7 still defaults to ANSI instead of WIDE, hence I have to use `Widestring` and `PWideChar`. Nowaday Delphi versions default to Unicode, so this would be `String` and `PChar`
- For the same reason the WIDE functions (ending with `W`) must be called.
- I execute `cmd.exe /U` because as per its manual to enable Unicode pipes.
- Made the buffer of `WideChar`s, too, instead of putting that to bytes only (`AnsiChar`). For nowadays Delphi versions you should have declared it simply as `Char`. **Most likely this is your fault.**
- Actually looking for errors that may occur.

```
function StringToWideString
( p: PAnsiChar  // Source to convert
; iLenSrc: Integer  // Source's length
; iSrcCodePage: DWord= CP_UTF8  // Source codepage
): WideString;  // Target is UTF-16
var
  iLenDest: Integer;
begin
  iLenDest:= MultiByteToWideChar( iSrcCodePage, 0, p, iLenSrc, nil, 0 );
  SetLength( result, iLenDest );
  if iLenDest> 0 then  // Otherwise we get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
  if MultiByteToWideChar( iSrcCodePage, 0, p, iLenSrc, PWideChar(result), iLenDest )= 0 then begin
    result:= '';
  end;
end;

function GetCmdOutput
( sCmd: Widestring  // Command line for process creation
; out sOut: Widestring  // Expected console output
; bExpectUtf8: Boolean  // Does the text make no sense? Then set this to TRUE.
): Word;  // Flag wise error indicator
const
  BUFLEN= $50000;  // 50* 1024= 51200
var
  vSA: TSecurityAttributes;  // For pipe creation
  vSI: TStartupInfo;  // To indicate pipe usage
  vPI: TProcessInformation;  // To later close handles
  hRead, hWrite: THandle;  // Pipe
  bRead: Boolean;  // Was ReadFile() successful?
  iRead: Cardinal;  // How many bytes were read by ReadFile()?
  pWide, pCmd: PWideChar;  // Read buffer in UTF-16; Command line for process creation
  pAnsi: PAnsiChar;  // Read buffer in UTF-8
  pBuf: Pointer;  // Read buffer in general, either ANSI or WIDE
label
  Finish;
begin
  // No error occurred yet, no output so far
  result:= 0;
  sOut:= '';

  // Creating 1 pipe with 2 handles: one for reading, other for writing
  vSA.nLength:= SizeOf( vSA );
  vSA.bInheritHandle:= TRUE;
  vSA.lpSecurityDescriptor:= nil;
  if not CreatePipe( hRead, hWrite, @vSA, 0 ) then begin
    result:= $01;  // GetLastError() for more details
    exit;
  end;

  // Prepare pipe usage when creating process
  FillChar( vSI, SizeOf( vSI ), 0 );
  vSI.cb:= SizeOf( vSI );
  vSI.dwFlags:= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  vSI.hStdInput:= GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  if vSI.hStdInput= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
    result:= $02;  // GetLastError() for more details
    goto Finish;
  end;
  vSI.hStdOutput:= hWrite;
  vSI.hStdError:= hWrite;

  // Create process via command line only
  sCmd:= sCmd+ #0;  // PWideChar must be NULL terminated
  GetMem( pCmd, 32000 );  // CreateProcessW() expects a writable parameter
  CopyMemory( @pCmd[0], @sCmd[1], Length( sCmd )* 2 );  // Copy bytes from Widestring to PWideChar
  if not CreateProcessW( nil, pCmd, nil, nil, TRUE, 0, nil, nil, vSI, vPI ) then begin
    result:= $04;  // GetLastError() for more details
    goto Finish;
  end;

  // Closing write handle of pipe, otherwise reading will block
  if not CloseHandle( hWrite ) then result:= result or $10;  // GetLastError() for more details
  hWrite:= 0;

  // Read all console output
  GetMem( pBuf, BUFLEN );
  try
    repeat
      bRead:= ReadFile( hRead, pBuf^, BUFLEN- 1, iRead, nil );  // Leave 2 bytes for NULL terminating WideChar
      if (bRead) and (iRead> 0) then begin
        if bExpectUtf8 then begin
          pAnsi:= pBuf;
          pAnsi[iRead]:= #0;
          sOut:= sOut+ StringToWideString( pAnsi, iRead );  // Convert UTF-8 into UTF-16
        end else begin
          pWide:= pBuf;
          pWide[iRead div 2]:= #0;  // Last character is NULL
          sOut:= sOut+ pWide;  // Add to overall output
        end;
      end;
    until (not bRead) or (iRead= 0);
  finally
    // Release process handles
    if not CloseHandle( vPI.hThread ) then result:= result or $20;  // GetLastError() for more details
    if not CloseHandle( vPI.hProcess ) then result:= result or $40;  // GetLastError() for more details;
  end;
  FreeMem( pBuf );

Finish:
  // Pipe must always be released
  if hWrite<> 0 then begin
    if not CloseHandle( hWrite ) then result:= result or $80;  // GetLastError() for more details
  end;
  if not CloseHandle( hRead ) then result:= result or $100;  // GetLastError() for more details
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sOut: Widestring;
  bUtf8: Boolean;
begin
  // In theory this should turn TRUE for you and FALSE for me.
  // If it doesn't work, of course, try setting it hardcoded to either TRUE or FALSE.
  bUtf8:= GetACP()= CP_UTF8;

  if GetCmdOutput
  ( 'cmd.exe /U /C dir /B M:\IN\*'  // What should be executed?
  , sOut  // Retrieving the output
  , bUtf8  // Will the output be UTF-16 or UTF-8?
  )<> 0 then Caption:= 'Error(s) occurred!';
  TntMemo1.Text:= sOut;
end;
```

It should also compile for newer Delphi versions. However, if [your Windows system's default codepage](https://superuser.com/a/1435645/650342) or [your process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69181417/4299358) is set to always use UTF-8 in API calls, you have to call my function with `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` as third parameter - that's why I must check the active codepage (ACP) first.

DOS never existed in Windows NT, [the "black" window is not DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe).

Comment: No go in latest Delphi.  Also tried string and pchar, rather then widestring and pwidechar.
It also needs to update the memo as it goes like the original code, not all at the end.
If anyone else can get the original code working with unicode please do.

Comment: Do you still want to keep your Windows and Delphi versions a secret? Because both differ a lot - you might use `A()` but with UTF-8 as codepage - then the bytes are neither ANSI nor WIDE (UTF-16), making both `AnsiString` and `String` the wrong choice.

Comment: Windows any version 10 and up 64 bit only.  Delphi 11.  Copying your exact code gave this sort of mojibake output in the memo.  潆摬牥倠呁⁈楬瑳湩൧潖畬敭猠牥慩⁬畮扭牥椠⁳㠷㘰㠭䙂ര䌊尺偁卐਍쓃
I do appreciate your thorough attempted answer.  And I realise DOS is long dead, just the name of the original procedure I found all those years ago.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely your ACP set to UTF-8, because "_潆摬牥倠呁⁈_" again is UTF-8 treated as UTF-16. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Same problem with the latest update.

Comment: bUtf8 is True here and not False as you thought.  If I force it to false I still get the mojibake output.

Comment: I wrote the opposite multiple times. You're also no help, as you didn't follow **any** link to give more details about if your EXE has a manifest or your Windows has that setting on. Debug my function step by step and inspect `pAnsi[0]`, then `pAnsi[1]`... up to `pAnsi[5]` and tell me the **hex** values of it (telling me only the characters is too ambiguous). Obviously after the line `pAnsi:= pBuf;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252033/discussion-between-some1else-and-amigojack).

Comment: Trying you function above with...
1. WideString changed to String
2. PWideChar changed to Char
3. Forcing True to the third parameter of your function gives this output for the tree command
C:\WINDOWS
+---addins
+---appcompat
�   +---appraiser
�   +---encapsulation
�   +---pca
+---apppatch
�   +---AppPatch64
�   +---Custom
�   �   +---Custom64
�   +---CustomSDB
�   +---en-US
�   +---MergeSdbFiles
�   +---MergeSdbFilesSource
It also does not update as it goes and opens a blank Window for the duration of the fucntion and tree command run time.

Comment: And you're sure [your launched Console encodes in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/4299358)? Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to force `TRUE`.

Comment: That fixed it!  And the original post code now works fine with unicode command line.  As long as that "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"checkbox is checked and the exe is compiled with Delphi 11 there are no other changes needed.  It "just works" now.

Comment: Well, I literally linked to that in my answer already: "_However, if [your Windows system's default codepage](https://superuser.com/a/1435645/650342) or..._" - so you did **not** follow all links to begin with. You should finally accept this answer or at least upvote it.