# Capturing command prompt unicode output correctly in a delphi memo

Tags: delphi, unicode

I have this fairly simple procedure that executes a command line cmd.exe /C command and displays the ongoing output in a memo on a form.

The problem is that it does not support unicode.

Form1 with a memo called CommandMemo and a button named Button1.  Here is the full code.

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CommandMemo: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  workdir:string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type TArg<T> = reference to procedure(const Arg: T);

procedure CaptureConsoleOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
const
  CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
  hRead: THandle;
  hWrite: THandle;
  suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
  piProcess: TProcessInformation;
  pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dRead: DWORD;
  dRunning: DWORD;
  dAvailable: DWORD;
begin
  saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSecurity.bInheritHandle := true;
  saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then
    try
      FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
      suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
      suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
      suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, PChar(WorkDir), suiStartup,
        piProcess) then
        try
          repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
            PeekNamedPipe(hRead, nil, 0, nil, @dAvailable, nil);
            if (dAvailable > 0) then
              repeat
                dRead := 0;
                ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                CallBack(dBuffer);
              until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
            Application.ProcessMessages;
          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        finally
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hRead);
      CloseHandle(hWrite);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     workdir:='c:\';
     CaptureConsoleOutput('cmd.exe /C tree','',
                procedure(const Line: PAnsiChar)
                begin
                    CommandMemo.Lines.Add(String(Line));
                end
     );
end;

end.
```

If you open a command prompt and execute tree from the c:\ directory you get the usual tree output with the tree branches shown like

```
    │   ├───x86_wpf-reachframework_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.551_none_0616e2623984b959
    │   ├───x86_wpf-windowsbase_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.532_none_5d706438588039e9
    │   └───x86_wpf-windowsbase_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.551_none_5d59c41658915874
    └───WUModels
```

When I use the above procedure the branch lines are shown as

```
    ª   +---x86_wpf-windowsbase_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.532_none_5d706438588039e9
    ª   +---x86_wpf-windowsbase_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.551_none_5d59c41658915874
    +---WUModels
```

Is anyone able to edit the CaptureConsoleOutput procedure to show unicode characters correctly in the commandmemo?
The tree output is just an example.  I am running some python code that disaplays non-english characters like chinese and russian, so I want them to be shown correctly in the memo too, so I need the output to support all unicode characters.

If the tree is changed to dir for example it works fine and displays as intended because there are only ASCII characters in the dir output.

Delphi 11 on Windows 10 and/or 11 X64.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75513057/capture-unicode-command-line-output

Comment: @fpiette Of course he did, since it's the same user asking the same things, making the same mistakes.

Comment: @AmigoJack The last post got into a mess and no solution in the end.  I know you got frustrated and left.  I have cut it all down to the bare minumum single procedure to show the issue with reproducable code.  If you could help fix this one I would really appreciate it.  If there was another way to contact you I would have discussed this offline with payment options.  Thanks.

Comment: @AmigoJack I did try your other fix (tried again just now and it still does not work in a fresh project).  The above function hides the command window correctly and updates the output as the commandline is updated.  It just needs whatver unicode tweaks can get it working correctly.